# Extracting a (sampled) time series from an SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an MS SQL data base which contains values stored with their time stamps. So my result table looks like this:

```
date        value
03.01.2016  11
19.01.2016  22
29.01.2016  33
17.02.2016  44
01.03.2016  55
06.03.2016  66
```

The time stamps don't really follow much of a pattern. Now, I need to extract weekly data from this: (sampled on Friday, for example)

```
date        value
01.01.2016  11     // friday
08.01.2016  11     // next friday
15.01.2016  11
22.01.2016  22
29.01.2016  33
05.02.2016  33
12.02.2016  33
19.02.2016  44
26.02.2016  44
04.03.2016  55
11.03.2016  66
```

Is there a reasonable way to do this directly in T-SQL?

I could reformat the result table using a C# or Matlab program, but it seems a bit weird, because I seem to again *query* the result table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution, which I find more readable. I'm first using a WHILE loop to generate the dates I'm looking for. Then I 'join' these dates to the actual data table using an OUTER APPLY, which looks up 'last value before a specific date'. Here's the code:

```
-- prepare in-memory table
declare @tbl table ( [date] date, [value] int )
insert into @tbl
 values
 ('2016-01-03','11'),
 ('2016-01-19','22'),
 ('2016-01-29','33'),
 ('2016-02-17','44'),
 ('2016-03-01','55'),
 ('2016-03-06','66')

-- query
declare @startDate date='2016-01-01';
declare @endDate date='2016-03-31';

with Fridays as (
    select @startDate as fridayDate
    union all
    select dateadd(day,7,fridayDate) from Fridays where dateadd(day,7,fridayDate)<=@endDate
)

select * 
from 
    Fridays f
    outer apply (
        select top(1) * from @tbl t
        where f.fridayDate >= t.[date]
        order by t.[value] desc
    ) as result

option (maxrecursion 10000)
```

Gives me:

```
fridayDate date       value
---------- ---------- -----------
2016-01-01 NULL       NULL
2016-01-08 2016-01-03 11
2016-01-15 2016-01-03 11
2016-01-22 2016-01-19 22
2016-01-29 2016-01-29 33
2016-02-05 2016-01-29 33
2016-02-12 2016-01-29 33
2016-02-19 2016-02-17 44
2016-02-26 2016-02-17 44
2016-03-04 2016-03-01 55
2016-03-11 2016-03-06 66
2016-03-18 2016-03-06 66
2016-03-25 2016-03-06 66
```

Thanks for everybody's ideas and support though!

Answer (score 1):

You Could possibly use a `CROSS JOIN` or `INNER JOIN`. I would personally go with the `INNER JOIN` as its much more efficient.

SAMPLE DATA:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(SomeDate  DATE
              , SomeValue VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO      #Temp(SomeDate
                 , SomeValue)
VALUES
      ('20160103'
     , 11),
      ('20160119'
     , 22),
      ('20160129'
     , 33),
      ('20160217'
     , 44),
      ('20160301'
     , 55),
      ('20160306'
     , 66)
```

QUERY USING CROSS JOIN:

```
;WITH T
    AS (SELECT *
        FROM   #Temp),
    D
    AS (
    SELECT SomeDate
        , SomeValue
    FROM     #Temp AS A
    UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 7, SomeDate)
        , SomeValue
    FROM     #Temp AS B
    UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 14, SomeDate)
        , SomeValue
    FROM   #Temp AS C)
    SELECT D.*
    FROM   T
          CROSS JOIN D
    WHERE  T.SomeValue = D.SomeValue
    ORDER BY SomeValue
          , SomeDate;
```

RESULT:

[image]

QUERY USING INNER JOIN:

```
;WITH T
    AS (SELECT *
        FROM   #Temp),
    D
    AS (
    SELECT SomeDate
        , SomeValue
    FROM     #Temp AS A
    UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 7, SomeDate)
        , SomeValue
    FROM     #Temp AS B
    UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 14, SomeDate)
        , SomeValue
    FROM   #Temp AS C)
    SELECT D.*
    FROM   T
          INNER JOIN D
    ON  T.SomeValue = D.SomeValue
    ORDER BY SomeValue
          , SomeDate;
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: hmm, the cross-join does work here, but in my use case the sampling rate is actually significantly higher than the data rate (about 1:10) .. so I would have to shift the dates 10x in order to not have gaps. I think I will generate the 'desired dates in the output'-vector using 'WHILE' (seems to work quite easily).

Comment: @Efrain would the INNER JOIN work for you. Try avoiding loops anywhere you can as they affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

This solution supports a maximum time window of 252 weeks from the first value time.

First row of your desired output is missing, because that friday is before the first value.
If needed, you can add it by mean of a UNION with a min of the table.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE ( [date] date, [value] int )

INSERT INTO @tbl
 VALUES
 ('2016-01-03','11'),
 ('2016-01-19','22'),
 ('2016-01-29','33'),
 ('2016-02-17','44'),
 ('2016-03-01','55'),
 ('2016-03-06','66')


;WITH DATA
    AS (
SELECT (S+P+Q) WeekNum, DATEADD( week, S + P + Q, MinDate ) Fridays, SubFri, [value]
   FROM ( SELECT 1 S UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 ) A
   CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 P UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 21 UNION SELECT 28 UNION SELECT 35 ) B
   CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 Q UNION SELECT 42 UNION SELECT 84 UNION SELECT 126 UNION SELECT 168 UNION SELECT 210 ) C
   CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT
        min ( DATEADD( day, -8 - DATEPART(weekday,[date]), [date] ) ) MinDate,
        max ( DATEADD( day, 13 - DATEPART(weekday,[date]), [date] ) ) MaxDate
      FROM @tbl
     ) MD
   LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DATEADD( day, 6 - DATEPART(weekday,[date]), [date] ) SubFri, [value] FROM @tbl ) Val
    ON SubFri<=DATEADD( week, S + P + Q, MinDate )
   WHERE DATEADD( week, S + P + Q, MinDate )<=MaxDate
)


SELECT DATA.Fridays, DATA.value
 FROM DATA
 INNER JOIN
 (
  SELECT Fridays, max(SubFri) MaxSubFri
   FROM DATA
   GROUP BY Fridays
 ) idx
  ON DATA.Fridays=idx.Fridays
   AND SubFri=MaxSubFri
 ORDER BY Fridays
```

Comment: Hm.. what does this union+crossjoin thing do? I'm afraid I can't really follow.

Comment: The CROSS JOIN part (subqueryes A, B and C) generates a recordset with 252 numbers (from 1 to 252).
The MD subquery find out the first and the last dates.

All the elements of your set of data are associated to all fridays starting from the one before the first date (-8) to the one after 2 weeks of the last date (13).

Comment: Your data begins with this row:
`03.01.2016  11`

Your output contains this row:
`01.01.2016  11     // friday`

The date of this Friday is before the first "sample".

The UNION hint is only to force this row to be shown; in my solution it is not shown.

Comment: All right, that seems to work rather beautifully. Unfortunately, my desired output vector is more than 252 rows long. My requirement is 'all data since January 1st 2000' which gives me about 900 rows, and that is also required to work in the next say .. 10 years. Do you think it's feasible to extend this union-magic to that many dates?

Comment: Yes, for sure. It's enough to modify the A, B and C subqueryes.     `FROM ( SELECT 1 S UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 ) A
   CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 P UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 20 UNION SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 40 UNION SELECT 50 UNION SELECT 60 UNION SELECT 70 UNION SELECT 80 UNION SELECT 90 ) B
   CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 Q UNION SELECT 100 UNION SELECT 200 UNION SELECT 300 UNION SELECT 400 UNION SELECT 500 UNION SELECT 600 UNION SELECT 700 UNION SELECT 800 UNION SELECT 900 ) C`

Comment: Btw, after a few weeks of more experience with SQL.. I must say that I prefer my solution from below, using a temporary table and cross apply. I find it a bit more straightforward and easier to use. I also only need to generate that 'Friday' table once.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `DATENAME` to get all the records of a certain day:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, date) = 'Friday'
```

This causes a scan in the query plan though so it would be advisable to have another column with the day of the week and you could just select `WHERE dayOfWeekCol = 'Friday'`

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not do the trick. I need to select *more* entries than what exists in the DB. Specifically, I think I need to first come up with a vector of dates at which I want to extract the latest data.